# Flink not forwarding Kafka metrics when parallelism greater than 1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a Flink job which reads from Kafka (v0.9) and writes to Redis. I want to monitor the `records-consumed-rate` and `records-lag-max` metrics emitted by Kafka which Flink should be able to forward. In this case, I am forwarding to Datadog.

When I start the job with a parallelism of 1, I see this metric emitted just fine. However, if I make the parallelism greater than 1, this metric is no longer forwarded. The job is running when parallelism > 1 because I can see the entries being written to Redis.

I'm running Flink (v1.6.2) on AWS EMR:

- master node: (1) m4.large
- core node: (1) c4.2xlarge
- num.task.managers: 1
- slots.per.task.manager: 7
- parallelism: 7

The parallelism is set by streamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(). Each Kafka Consumer is instantiated with the same group.id and a unique client.id.

The DD agent is running just fine on the cluster. Many metrics are being emitted such as numberOfCompletedCheckpoints and upTime etc.

Is there any reason Flink would not be forwarding these metrics from Kafka if the parallelism is greater than 1?

**Update:**
I also tried sending a custom DD metric (`counter.inc()`) from the Redis RichSinkFunction. When the parallelism=1, the metric is sent fine. When parallelism=7, the metric is not sent however it is being called (added a debug line). So it seems its not limited to the forwarded metrics from Kafka.

Comment: Not sure how DataDog works, as I have never used it, but when You set parallelism > 1, Flink sends separate metrics for each of the TaskManagers involved in the processing, so maybe that's an issue in Your case? I have been using Flink with Prometheus and there have been no issues with parallelism > 1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the size of the HTTPRequest was to large the higher the parallelism which makes sense. I was getting back "Request Entity Too Large" however the exception wasn't logging out correctly so I missed it.

It seems that the Flink [DatadogHttpReporter](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6.2/flink-metrics/flink-metrics-datadog/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/metrics/datadog/DatadogHttpReporter.java#L118) does not take the size of the request into consideration when building it. I modified the Reporter to limit the number of metrics per request to 1000. Now the metrics are showing up just fine.